# Uncheck all shipping metod radio buttons

Tags: checkout, shipping-methods

I would like to uncheck all shipping methods. When a customer is on a checkout page, radio button is not preselected (all circles are empty).

Comment: which version of magento?

Answer (score -1):

copy template

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method\available.phtml
```

to

```
app\design\frontend\Your-Pacakage\Your-Theme\default\template\checkout\onepage\shipping_method\available.phtml
```

changed below code ~line no 44

```
 <?php if ($_sole) : ?>
     <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" checked="checked" /></span>
 <?php else: ?>
      <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>"<?php if($_rate->getCode()===$this->getAddressShippingMethod()) echo ' checked="checked"' ?> class="radio"/>
```

changed to

```
<?php if ($_sole) : ?>
   <span class="no-display"><input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" /></span>
 <?php else: ?>
     <input name="shipping_method" type="radio" value="<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" id="s_method_<?php echo $_rate->getCode() ?>" class="radio"/>
```

Comment: Once it reload shipping method then it also uncheck previously selected shipping method.